# Onclick event for input field doesn't work while accessibility screen reader is running

Tags: android, html, accessibility, talkback

Onclick event for input field doesn't work while accessibility screen reader is running.

I use this HTML example for many years. But since Android 8, it doesn't work. Until Android 8, the onclick event was triggered by a double-tap action while the screen reader is running.

```
<input type="text" name="pwd1" id="pwd1" onclick="alert('test');" />
```

I want it to work as before Android 8. I want the onclick event for a div to act as a double tap. But since Android 8, it doesn't work.

Comment: If I double tap, the system keypad appears, not the onclick event(alert).

Comment: how about just using onFocus instead?

Comment: I have a reason you should use onclick...
Is this a problem with the Android accessibility software?
If so, is there no solution?

Comment: Would you mind explaining your reason? From a more wide perspective it seems weird to me to use `onclick` over `onfocus`. The [Android Accessibility Help](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151827?hl=en) explains "double tap" to "Select focused item". Talkback is not a pointing device, but onclick is a pointer event. I change in this behaviour makes sense to me.

Comment: Are you using Talkback and Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I'm using talkback and chrome.
I need to use onclick and onfocus behavior differently because I use auto focus on other field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using onclick on an input text field is anyway a bad practice.
You should probably use onfocus instead.

Reasons why you shouldn't use onclick include:

- It isn't triggered when the field is focused using the keyboard or anything other than the mouse
- It may be triggered even if the field is already in focus, for example when selecting or moving the insertion point

You probably want to do something when the field gets the focus, not when the field is clicked; in that case, use onfocus.